# Can't open LASzip GUI on Windows 10?

Tags: installation, lidar, gui, windows-10, laszip

I am new to liDAR and trying to extract some .laz files to .las.

It seems that this should be a pretty straightforward process in Windows using the LASzip GUI, however I am not able to open the application.

I have not tried to use the command prompt to accomplish this task as mentioned in [Converting LiDAR files from LAZ to LAS format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188170/converting-lidar-files-from-laz-to-las-format).

I would like to try to use the GUI first. When I try to open the laszip.exe application it seems to open for a second and then close.

Does anyone have this issue and/or any guidance?

Comment: I read that thread but where it directs the Windows user to just open the GUI, I cannot open it.  It seems to appear for a second and then disappears and I am wondering if anyone else has experienced this.

Comment: @SteveC Please [edit] your question to include all extra information (like your comment above) and any other detail about what steps you follow and what happens as you work through them.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and walk us through the steps you used to install laszip?

Comment: I just edited the post.  Thanks for looking at this again.  I assure you my question is not the same as the one mentioned by Andre Silva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem. I've downloaded the laszip.exe file from 'binaries' from [laszip.org](http://www.laszip.org/.). Then, double clicked `laszip.exe` and the GUI opened normally.

[image]

Also, I did a quick search in Google looking for the same issue for LASzip or LAStools and did not find anything. Perhaps you can ask this in the [LAStools Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/lastools), but make sure to add more details in the question, for example, how you installed laszip, what does it happen when you call it from the command prompt, if you run it as administrator or something else, etc.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion.  My laszip.exe file was from a different source.  It did not work.  I deleted it and downloaded the file from laszip.org and it worked fine.