# Saving LAZ files to different location from input (LAS) files?

Tags: lidar, command-line, file-path, save, laszip

All of the command line examples I'm seeing show how to create LAZ files in the same folder as the LAS files, e.g.:

```
C:\Folder\tools>laszip F:\Folder\LAS_points\*.las
```

Unfortunately, I don't have enough space in that directory to create and save LAZ files there. I need to save them elsewhere. How can I edit the command line to get the LAZ files to save to, say, `G:\Folder\LAZ_points`?

Comment: @AndreSilva True, an answer to that question now mentions -odir and saving to another folder, but it looks like you edited that a few hours ago, after I posted this Q. So I'm not sure I'd call this one a duplicate as that would imply your answer existed previously. Apologies if I'm not understanding. I'm not a power user.

Comment: I edited my answer there to reference your Q/A here, so it is clear this Q was not a duplicate when it was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague and I figured it out (she figured out "odir"):

```
C:\somefolder\tools>laszip -i F:\anotherfolder\LAS_points\*.las -odir G:\yetanotherfolder\LAZ_points
```

This will create LAZ files in a folder for all of the LAS files in another folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the output location using the `-o` option. For example:

```
laszip -i lidar.las -o lidar.laz
```

Comment: Would you mind including a more readable example like I gave above in my question, including dummy file paths? I'm having a hard time translating what you wrote into the way it should actually be written in command line. (Sorry, I'm not a command line expert in the slightest).

Comment: For example: C:\Folder\tools>laszip -i F:\Folder\LAS_points\\*.las -o G:\Folder\LAZ_points<WHAT GOES HERE?>

Comment: I could make this work with single files (saving in a different directory using the `-o` identifier if file path is specified); but did not succeed with wildcards `*` (only succeeded with `-odir` for this case).